# Determine if matlab runtime is installed(preferably using Java)

Tags: java, matlab, runtime

I have a Java application that at some point calls on a Matlab `executable`. For now I just tell the user to install the included runtime manually but I would like to avoid it.

What I'm looking for is a way of determining what version of Matlab runtime(if any) is installed and in case the required version is not installed I'll prompt the user with an option of running the installer.

**How can I check for Matlab runtime(preferably using Java)?**

Comment: How do you invoke the executable?  You could just write a small Matlab program which returns the version and try to execute that.  If it fails, ask the user to install Matlab.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I create a `process` and redirect its stream to my application. A don't have Matlab only the `executables` so I cant really "write a small Matlab program", isn't there a registry entry for the mcc or even a Batch command that can tell me the version(or not instaled)?

Comment: If you are talking about the registry, I assume you are specifically looking for a solution on Windows?

Comment: Matlab has a trial.  Perhaps it would be a good idea to play with it in a virtual machine.

Comment: Slightly unrelated: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97012-how-can-i-check-the-availability-of-the-matlab-compiler-runtime-mcr-on-a-windows-machine-from-a-c (check if library can be loaded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're talking about running compiled matlab code, right ?

For recent Matlab Runtime releases, you can look in the registry for following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MathWorks\MATLAB Runtime\9.0
```

Depending on runtime the path may change, for instance for version 8.2 it is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MathWorks\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\8.2
```

Look into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MathWorks` and adapt to the version you have.

NB1: Old version of the runtime do not have entry in the registry (for instance version 7.4 (R2006a) doesn't have entry.

NB2: Carefull for path virtualization to 'Wow6432Node' if running in x32 mode on a x64 machine (path virutalization it is normally handle by the system anyway, so it should be no problem).

Comment: I'm looking for version 7.15 and as I understand there is no entry for versions below 7.4... Can it be that the older runtime installations are so "clunky" that there is no clean way to check for them?

Comment: Is it at all an option to execute the `mcc` command and check the stream for 'mcc' is not recognized...

Comment: 7.15 is more recent than 7.4 (R2006a) ... Look at registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MathWorks` if you can't find any entry you'll have to check if folder `($ProgramFiles)\MATLAB\MATLAB Component Runtime\v715` exists (this is how i was managing thiings at the time I was using R2006a).

Comment: I'll try that once I get the runtime installed... will accept the answer after the test. Thank you for the effort.