# Install Matlab MCR as part of the C# Installer Wizard

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I have wrote a program `HelloApp` with Matlab and packaged it as .NET Assembly using `deploytool` as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/getting-started-net-applications-using-matlab-compiler-sdk-100367.html?s_tid=srchtitle). As a result I have got `helloapp.dll` library, which I included into my Visual Studio 2015 as a reference, so I can run Matlab methods directly from C#. To run the code without Matlab installed, the end user needs Matlab Runtime (MCR) installed at least.

Now I want to create an installer for my C# program. I have came across [Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) which provides some tools to create program setup wizard. The problem is, I don't know how to include download and setup of [MCR package](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) as a step in installation process to ensure the user has all the required prerequisites in order for program to run.

Comment: Is it necessary to install MCR always or should the setup check if the corresponding Matlab installation exists and skip the installation if the right version is already installed? To my knowledge you need MCR or MATLAB in the right version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is not really an answer, but comment area in question was too short ...

I don't know much about [VS2015 Installer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) as I personnally use [innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). Anyway to check if runtime is installed on target machine you can look if following key exists in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MathWorks\MATLAB Runtime\9.0
```

See my posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149828/684399) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34786213/684399) for further details.

NB1: Note that installer for Matlab runtime is very large (about 1 GB). I would not package it with application to deploy, but just warn the user to install it separately.

NB2: I think Mathworks is packaging `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\toolbox\compiler\deploy\win64\InstallAgent.zip` (~66MB) rather than `MCRInstall.exe` (~1GB) when deploying standalone installer with `deploytool` for downloading the runtime during install but I don't know how it works.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Actually, I have already found your posts before you replied and managed to package it with InnoSetup :) I am not sure about InstallAgent.zip, I packaged it with Online MCR installer, which I got during the deploy. it's about 2MB in size and I included it as a step in installation wizard. It's downloading and instaling about 500 MB and takes forever even with 100 mbit/s network

Comment: Yes, the amont of files to install on target machines for the runtime to work is really huge ! Almost the size of Matlab environment itself + need to install side-by-side all rutime versions if compiling with different MCR versions ;)